# Сложное регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

text `{msg ru key}` text text `{msg key [m=1,p=1]}` text `{msg ru key
[m=la la|p=1]}` text

Как видим в ней есть тег `{msg}`.

Как составить регулярку так, чтобы она разбирала этот тег?
Если тег написан так: `{msg ru key}` то тогда вывод нужно такой:

```
array(
   0 => ru,
   1 => key
);
```

Если тег написан так: `{msg ru key [m=la la|p=1]}` то тогда вывод нужно такой:

```
array(
   0 => ru,
   1 => key,
   2 => [m=la la|p=1]
);
```

Если тег написан так: `{msg key [m=la la|p=1]}` то тогда вывод нужно такой:

```
array(
   0 => key,
   1 => [m=la la|p=1]
);
```

Comment: Вы решили написать свой шаблонизатор?

Comment: Используйте [`(?:(?!^)\G|{msg)\s+\K(?:\w+|\[[^][]*])(?=[^}]*})`](https://regex101.com/r/4Huh23/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew То, что нужно! Благадарю, пожалуйста, оформите как ответ, чтобы я выбрал в качестве решения. спасибо!

Comment: @vihtor, нет. Это и является уже шаблоном, мне нужно было просто массив  собрать, для так сказать замены вхождений в уже имеющемся массиве данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы найти несколько совпадений внутри какой-то определённой подстроки, нужно использовать шаблон на основе оператора `\G` (=начало строки или конец предыдущего совпадения).

```php
'~(?:(?!^)\G|{msg)\s+\K(?:\w+|\[[^][]*])(?=[^}]*})~'
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/4Huh23/1).

- `(?:(?!^)\G|{msg)` - конец предыдущего совпадения (`(?!^)\G`) или (`|`) подстрока `{msg`
- `\s+` - 1 и более пробельных символов
- `\K` - оператор, очищающий буфер текущего совпадения (будто ничего не нашли до сих пор)
- `(?:\w+|\[[^][]*])` - одно из двух:

  - `\w+` - 1 и более букв, цифр или `_`
  - `|` - или
  - `\[[^][]*]` - подстрока вида `[...]` (между скобками не может быть других скобок)
- `(?=[^}]*})` - (блок предварительного просмотра вперёд) после данного места в строке не может быть 0 и более символов, отличных от `}`, а потом `}`.

Если просто использовать это выражение для строки, в которой есть несколько подстрок `{msg...}`, найдены будут все совпадения, но они не будут группированы (см. [пример кода на PHP](https://ideone.com/3w32IT)). Чтобы их сгруппировать, надо использовать немного кода:

```php
$re = '/(?:(?!^)\G|({msg))\s+\K(?:\w+|\[[^][]*])(?=[^}]*})/';
$str = 'text {msg ru key} text text {msg key [m=1,p=1]} text {msg ru key [m=la la|p=1]} text';
$results = [];
$tmp = -1;
preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) use (&$results, &$tmp) {
    if (!empty($m[1])) {
        array_push($results, array($m[0]));
        $tmp=$tmp+1;
    } else {
        $results[$tmp][] = $m[0];
    }
}, $str);
print_r($results);
```

См. [пример кода на PHP](https://ideone.com/3w32IT). Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ru
            [1] => key
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => key
            [1] => [m=1,p=1]
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ru
            [1] => key
            [2] => [m=la la|p=1]
        )

)
```

Comment: Честно говоря, неясно, за что 2 минуса. Всё тут кристально ясно, примеры и объяснение приведены.